# How do I extend the desktop to the third monitor using a Displaylink USB-to-VGA adapter?

Tags: multiple-monitors, displaylink

I have a DisplayLink USB-to-VGA adapter (17e9:0198 Newnham Research) I would like to add to my system (eventually two). I am running Linux  3.5.0-19-generic #30~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 14 21:43:28 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux and Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

I have an Asus G74Sx with the main screen and a second monitor on the VGA port. The DisplayLink-connected monitor shows green unless I hit CTRL-ALT-F1 in which case the other two monitors go blank and a login screen appears on the monitor connected to the DisplayLink. I can login and have a text-mode display.

What I really would like is to extend the desktop to the third monitor. Can anyone help?

Comment: sorry, must have deleted "CTRL-ALT-F1" which is what I hit to get to the login screen